# Does the soul have thinking power?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, philosophy, sankhya

Does the soul have thinking power? Or all the experiences are stored as latent memory that later builds karmic tendencies, the phase transition point for them being Self Realization?

Comment: Hello! please ask one question per post .. right now you've asked 11 ... in it's current state the Q will be closed.

Comment: you just wrote this question. So, yes. Souls think :-)

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman , I consider soul as Aatma but Aatma is untouched by Human sences and For thinking about something we use sences then How can we imagine that *Aatma could understand, think, feel* etc.?

Comment: Senses are sight, sound, smell, taste, touch Not think… these are all input to your thinking..to your aatma